# Singledatapoint shared by multiple dataseries, connection problem

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to creae a timeline plot showing four different data series. The first data entry is a singlepoint though, from which the four series should originate from, but they don't. How can i tell all of them to start at t0 not at t1, without manually altering my original dataframe?

This is a mixed problem. Either the Dataframe is manipulated or ggplot can be told what is wanted.

---

So I measured a substance that is then split in four different reactors and after the first day measured seperatly. My dataframe (plotdataframe =pldf) has one entry for t0 and four entries from then onwards. y is the measurmentvalue and shape is the differentiation of the four lines.

The differentiation ("Versuchsbezeichnung" & "Reaktorbezeichung") is "All" for t0 and onwards they are "30.1", "30.2", "50.1" and "50.2".

The df has a column for the experiment (2 levels) and the reactors (5 leves, "All" for t0 and "30.1", "30.2", "50.1" and "50.2" for the rest. With every day (t) and reactor there are about 20 rows associated.

here is part of the pldf with dput() and reduced to t0, t1 and t2 (still looks messy, sorry) :

```
structure(list(X = c(599L, 619L, 639L, 659L, 679L, 699L, 719L, 
738L, 757L, 776L, 796L, 816L, 836L, 856L, 875L, 894L, 914L, 934L, 
954L, 974L, 994L, 1013L, 1032L, 1052L, 1072L, 1092L, 1112L, 1132L, 
1151L, 1171L, 1191L, 1211L, 1231L, 1292L, 1312L, 1332L, 1352L, 
1372L, 1393L, 1414L, 1435L, 1456L, 1477L, 1498L, 1519L, 1540L, 
1560L, 1581L, 1602L, 1623L, 1788L, 1809L, 1830L, 1851L, 1872L, 
1893L, 1914L, 1935L, 1956L, 1977L, 1998L, 2019L, 2040L, 2061L, 
2082L, 2103L, 2124L, 2145L, 2166L, 2187L, 2208L, 2228L, 2249L, 
2270L, 2291L, 2312L, 2333L, 2354L, 2375L, 2396L, 2417L, 2438L
), Datum.Probenahme = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("01.07.2019", "05.06.2019", 
"06.06.2019", "07.06.2019", "08.06.2019", "09.06.2019", "10.06.2019", 
"11.06.2019", "12.06.2019", "13.06.2019", "14.06.2019", "15.06.2019", 
"16.06.2019", "20.06.2019", "21.06.2019", "22.06.2019", "23.06.2019", 
"24.06.2019", "25.06.2019", "26.06.2019", "28.06.2019", "30.06.2019"
), class = "factor"), Uhrzeit.Probenahme = structure(c(50L, 12L, 
10L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 19L, 12L, 
12L, 22L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 24L, 12L, 12L, 31L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 
5L, 9L, 20L, 16L, 7L, 11L, 19L, 21L, 15L, 20L, 30L, 26L, 1L, 
2L, 6L, 3L, 38L, 35L, 39L, 43L, 46L, 20L, 23L, 28L, 30L, 20L, 
22L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 43L, 36L, 27L, 32L, 29L, 34L, 
37L, 42L, 35L, 45L, 41L, 48L, 49L, 47L, 44L, 40L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L), .Label = c("09:23", "09:29", "09:37", "09:40", "09:42", 
"09:43", "09:47", "09:50", "09:51", "09:52", "09:55", "10:00", 
"10:05", "10:06", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", "10:15", "10:16", 
"10:20", "10:24", "10:25", "10:30", "10:34", "10:35", "10:36", 
"10:37", "10:40", "10:43", "10:45", "10:50", "10:51", "10:55", 
"10:57", "11:00", "11:01", "11:03", "11:04", "11:05", "11:06", 
"11:07", "11:09", "11:10", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", "11:20", 
"11:21", "11:25", "12:10"), class = "factor"), Versuchsbezeichnung = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("MUN", "WAS"), class = "factor"), Probenzeitpunkt = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("t0", "t1", "t10", "t11", 
"t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9"), class = "factor"), 
    Reaktorbezeichnung = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L), .Label = c("Alle", "T30.1", "T30.2", "T50.1", "T50.2"
    ), class = "factor"), eingestellte_Temperatur = c(NA, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 
    30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, NA, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 
    30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 
    30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 
    30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L), Parameter_lang = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "substance", class = "factor"), 
    mittelwert = c(195.510146467184, 590.04453797041, 650.046710519628, 
    805.023970909082, 680.056275644273, 605.038628373497, 655.013494757377, 
    510.014882632685, 535.033292951283, 670.029819108804, 675.023180234177, 
    635.030532865876, 705.020509801388, 700.016350845922, 630.031948130196, 
    575.020958779739, 515.034675161434, 515.010423214009, 484.525917325803, 
    525.034977749943, 535.030449153043, 545.005715243447, 540.041962411875, 
    545.046361460258, 461.558379907788, 510.029446766068, 600.036907210817, 
    520.031560570813, 515.023911897655, 645.052575729496, 705.012975914544, 
    550.022784174821, 560.017740283, 630.066260242174, 675.022704031091, 
    545.053372419458, 540.016063199975, 700.028692986007, 604.992609005687, 
    545.038604346887, 500.023450688633, 685.031134646166, 765.044624693392, 
    575.045832850911, 545.018905606243, 9.30989225859789, 14.6996919068786, 
    20.2006993402116, 11.6396196601576, 9.81990236026879, 29.7991367947917, 
    29.1989874363788, 4.11997199560799, 4.44042193773157, 32.9990403063925, 
    57.5020579022581, 21.0483199248758, 22.0038515217912, 90.4030580857021, 
    89.000336284423, 8.34032878685458, 10.3604802171955, 96.1034261675684, 
    105.004535949448, 8.89931984186634, 9.92024857606832, 101.002678657527, 
    132.007031226063, 10.7206828322988, 10.7809908792647, 107.003512180122, 
    101.001589580275, 12.3191266322172, 10.0618514094455, 102.005883436079, 
    93.29828183675, 8.46966678357295, 5.40058933971296, 45.7032091854773, 
    49.8010426068819, 7.61983731205152, 6.9002829183213)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-82L))
```

---

This is what I try to work with:

```
ggplot(data = pldf, aes(x = day, y = mittelwert, col = Versuchsbezeichnung, shape = Reaktorbezeichnung)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, 100))
```

Resulting in: [Current plot where the firstpoint for 2 different experiment runs are not connected to the rest of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUJ7f.png)

A temporary fix for standard plotting was this:

`reaktor301 <- pldf[pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung %in% c("Alle", "T30.1"),]
reaktor302 <- pldf[pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung %in% c("Alle", "T30.2"),]
reaktor501 <- pldf[pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung %in% c("Alle", "T50.1"),]
reaktor502 <- pldf[pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung %in% c("Alle", "T50.2"),]`

but how can that work in ggplot? I mean how can i tell ggplot to draw data from four different dataframes?

Formerly i had not included the df and am sorry that it looks messy i dont know how to integrate it better (more pretty) since i am new to r and stackoverflow and all.

---

I want the graph to show lines from t0 to t11.
I probably end up just copy the row of "Alle" for times in the original df. But if you know a way for the future, an answer would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please give us a working example, so we can replicate your problem. I do not have a `plddf` data frame on my hard drive. This does not have to be the original data, but some sort of data that show the same behaviour. You know your data well, but 
I don't , so for me your explanations are *Kauderwelsch*.

Comment: Thank you. I get that my first try was messy, sorry. I hope the format I provided the df in is suitable for replication. I copied the values from r since I didn't know how to attach the df.csv I have saved.

Comment: Sorry, I can't load your data. You have 9 columns but only 6 variable names. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to use [dput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput). Also, the example data are not sufficient to replicate your plot. You can randomize the data or sample it if you cannot post the original data, but if you have two types of experiments and four reactor classes then they all need to be in the example data.

Comment: But generally, you can always (i) make a new data frame which contains all necessary data, or (ii) add a mapping in `geom_lines` calls, eg. `geom_line(aes(fill=otherdf$whatever))`.

Comment: ok thank you. now the datafraem is created via dput(), hope that is what you meant

Comment: PERFECT! That is great. I did a lot of unnecessary work, then ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I am starting to understand your problem. But first, an adjustment to your data:

```
pldf$day <- as.numeric(gsub("t", "", pldf$Probenzeitpunkt))
```

Yeah, I think that you should create a copy of your data frame and for each occurrence of "Alle", add a line with the zero point:

```
n.react <- length(unique(pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung)) - 1 # should be 4
reactors <- setdiff(unique(pldf$Reaktorbezeichnung), "Alle")

pldf2 <- pldf %>% filter(Reaktorbezeichnung == "Alle") %>% 
         mutate(count=rep(n.react, 2)) %>% uncount(count) %>% 
         mutate(Reaktorbezeichnung=rep(reactors, 2)) %>%
         rbind(pldf) %>% filter(Reaktorbezeichnung != "Alle")
```

Explanation: first, we take only the lines containing "Alle". Next, we create a temporary column, `count`, which is then used to replicate each of the rows with the `uncount` function (so if count was, say, 4, instead of one row, we get 4). Next, we change the  "Reaktorbezeichnung" from "Alle" to the possible values, each of them twice (once per trial type) and finally we bind to the original pldf and remove the "Alle". Uff.

Bottom line is, for each of the "Alle" lines pldf2 should now contain four lines, where "Alle" is replaced by "T30.1", "T30.2", "T50.1", "T50.2". For the points esthetics, you need the original data frame. For the lines, however, you need this modified data frame.

Then you can do

```
ggplot(data = pldf, aes(x = day, y = mittelwert, col = Versuchsbezeichnung, shape =       Reaktorbezeichnung)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pldf2, mapping=aes(x=day, y=mittelwert, col=Versuchsbezeichnung)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, 100))
```

Since I cannot use your data snippet, I have made a simulated data which gives a similar figure:

```
pldf <- data.frame(React=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=12), 
                  day=rep(1:6, 8), 
                  trial=rep(rep(c("WAS", "MUN"), each=6), 4))
pldf$y <- 10 * as.numeric(factor(pldf$trial)) + rnorm(48)
pldf <- rbind(pldf, data.frame(React=rep("Alle", 2), 
    day=0, 
    trial=c("WAS", "MUN"), y=c(5, 10)))
```

With your commands, this gives a similar picture:

[image]

OK, I use my suggested commands:

```
pldf2 <- pldf %>% filter(React == "Alle") %>% 
         mutate(count=c(4, 4)) %>% uncount(count) %>% 
         mutate(React=rep(LETTERS[1:4], 2)) %>%
         rbind(pldf) %>% filter(React != "Alle")


ggplot(data=pldf, aes(x=day, y=y, color=trial, shape=React)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=pldf2, aes(x=day, y=y, color=trial)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, 5)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

Is this what you wanted?

[image]

OK, Now that I showed that you can do it, I will try to discourage you from doing it. Why do you need an additional symbol for just one point? Why do you want to unnecessarily introduce confusion to the viewer of your chart? It is quite obvious from the figure that all lines of one color originate at one point. You should always strive to reduce the amount of ink and symbols you show on your data. For example: is it important to distinguish T30.1 from T30.2 on the plot? Is the reactor type at all an important thing to show?

Comment: :-) ggplot is tricky sometimes, but basically, when i doubt, instead of fiddling with ggplot, fiddle with the data: ggplot usually is driven by what the data is.

Comment: I agrre with your last comment whole heartedly. And since i dont want to hold on to "Alle" i will just substitute all your pldf2 with pldf. That looks great and is a totally 'happifying' solution. (Hope you are not too mad about the delayed df entrie at the top. i had to spend some time figuring out how to cut the df and such things)