# Transferring a data frame from R Studio Cloud to GoogleSheets seems prohibitively slow

Tags: r, google-sheets

I have a data frame in R Studio cloud that is 85 rows by 207 columns (ultimately it may be as wide as 366 columns). The actual data is created using the code in this thread:

[Function to generate multiple rows of vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271836/function-to-generate-multiple-rows-of-vectors-in-r/57273669?noredirect=1#comment101047360_57273669][1])

Now that I have the data frame set up, I'm trying to use the googlesheets library to transfer it to an existing sheet (and will periodically update it as I get more data). I'm using this code to edit the google sheet:

```
gs_edit_cells(sheet, ws = "Test", input=data, anchor="A2")
```

I let it think for a long time (more than an hour) and it sat there with "Range affected by the update" and it never went through. If I slice it into several segments (doing say 30 or 60 or 90 columns at a time) then it does transfer but is prohibitively slow. This isn't a huge dataset, is there something I could improve in my code? I have loaded the sheet in advance and it does recognize it.

Comment: Is the answer that the googlesheets library just isn't really built to transfer any quantity of data that's not a small table?

Comment: Anyone have any experience with this? It's still incredibly slow. I'd love to be able to transfer the data I have and it really isn't that large.