# How to get the top most number of distinct values from a dataset

Tags: r

I am playing around with the Los Angeles Police Data that I got via the Office of the Mayor's website. From 2017-2018, I am attempting to see what charges and the amount of each specific charge were given out in Council District 5. `CHARGE` and `CITY_COUNCIL_DIST` are the two variables/columns I am looking at.

I used `table(ArrestData$CHARGE)` to count the number of distinct values.

I realized that there are over 2400 unique entries, therefore most of the entries are being omitted. I am wondering if there is code to see which 5 "CHARGES" are being mostly given out by the LAPD.

Additionally, I am attempting to find the top 5 charges in one specific `Council District` (again, another variable/column), is there code for this?

Aside: 
How can I add sample data to my post? What are the steps to do so on RStudio? 
Someone asked me to do this in a previous post, but I am not sure how to do so. They told me to use `dput(head(df,n))` but my data is too large, even with using 10 rows. They told me to do it through RScript, but I am not sure what they mean

Comment: Here's a post for future reference on how to add data: [Reproducibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think that using an aggregate function may help here. If your data is just CHARGE and CITY_COUNCIL_DIST, then the code might look something like this:

```
aggregate(.~CITY_COUNCIL_DIST + CHARGE, ArrestData, count)
```

I'm not terribly advance at R yet, so that code might need some tweaks with your actual data. Once you have the aggregate, you can order your data:

```
agg.data[order(agg.data, descending=TRUE),]
```

I'm really no help with dput, sorry!

Comment: Also, I recently posted a question and was confused about dput. Here's the thread I found and followed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a reference to the actual dataset/sample data will be helpful to creating a solution.  This will help the post adhere to the reproducibility standards that others have mentioned.  For the sake of this example we will explicitly create a dataset.

```
ArrestData <- data.frame(
  CHARGE=c("CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA",
           "CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA","CHARGEA",
           "CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB",
           "CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB","CHARGEB",
           "CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC",
           "CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC","CHARGEC",
           "CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED",
           "CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED","CHARGED",
           "CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE",
           "CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE","CHARGEE",
           "CHARGEF","CHARGEF","CHARGEF","CHARGEF",
           "CHARGEF","CHARGEF","CHARGEF","CHARGEF",
           "CHARGEG","CHARGEG","CHARGEG",           
           "CHARGEG","CHARGEG","CHARGEG",
           "CHARGEH","CHARGEH",
           "CHARGEH","CHARGEH",
           "CHARGEI",
           "CHARGEI"
           ),
  CITY_COUNCIL_DIST=c(0,5)
)
```

This code should work, assuming that your dataset is named `ArrestData` and your `CHARGE`/`CITY_COUNCIL_DIST` are also named as stated.  The below code will include the top 5 `CHARGE`'s by `CITY_COUNCIL_DIST` for all `CITY_COUNCIL_DIST`.

```
#install these packages if you do not have them

install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("dplyr")

#make sure these libraries are present
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ArrestData %>% 
  group_by(CHARGE, CITY_COUNCIL_DIST) %>%
  summarize(count=n()) %>% 
  arrange(CITY_COUNCIL_DIST, desc(count)) %>%
  group_by(CITY_COUNCIL_DIST) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(desc(count), ties.method="min")) %>% 
  filter(rank<=5)
```

In order to filter out only the results for `CITY_COUNCIL_DIST` 5, you will need to change the `filter` statement to something like the following:(depending on what your `CITY_COUNCIL_DIST` values actually are)

```
filter(rank<=5, CITY_COUNCIL_DIST==5)
```