# I have following data for R . I want to plot bar graphs in following manner

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a csv data and I want to create bar graphs using R according to the image. Could you please help me. I have attached data(csv file)[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cmZazdW8hULYMd4zevQXXyhyLsWRm1Ng/view?usp=sharing) and image [image]

```
c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, instead sharing a screenshot of your data, can you use `dput` to give us a sample of data?

Comment: So far steps tried  Step1) Imported CSV . Step2) Tried plotting using barplot(columname). Step3) Used ggplot2 library but all in vain . R generated bar graph but there is not good spacing ,names are colliding in it.   @yifyan I have posted data in csv . I have just not put names as it is confidential .

Comment: Please also share the codes you used for doing the steps described above. Also, use `dput()` to provide the csv data  as a code snippet isntead of sharing a csv file. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: You need to be more specific about what problems you met. For example? Do you have problems in flipping the coordinates? coloring bars using conditions? sorting bars by marks? Adding text labels? There are so many possible questions. We can't help you unless you show us the codes you used.

Comment: i just used barplot() and it provides plots , but since there are 100 data points it results in overlap and there is no clear distinction