# Multiple lines in different facet using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I am having a very simple logical problem in ggplot.
Please see the attached graph.
[image: Graph attached here]

I want multiple lines in each facet, I am getting only one line.
Each set of values need to be connected individually across the Attribute.
The code I have used is :

```
library(ggplot2)
h <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(Attribute, Values, colour = Classe)) 
h + geom_point(size = 0.7) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ Classe, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Can you dput(df) and add output to post? As in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49995752/11437205

Comment: Seems you should add a grouping variable in `geom_line()` that indicates what observations belong together.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are looking for in your end result.  If you want all the lines in the same plot, you don't need the facets.  You've already setup in `aes(...)` the variable to separate color, so if you take what you have and remove `facet_wrap(...)`, you'll  end up with one plot that contains all line and point colors together.  If you want to facet your data, then you can add back in the `facet_wrap(...)` function, but you should choose another variable to use for faceting: something else in place of "Classe".