# Counting the number of unique vector in columns of input data in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out the number of unique vector in selected input using my data. 
However, all of the results of the variables' `length(unique(x))` is `1`. 
Could you help me how to fix this problem?

Here's my code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    box(width = 6, height=200, title ="File select", 
        fileInput("file","select file", buttonLabel = "file", accept = c(".csv")),
        DTOutput('dt')),
  selectInput("sel","select",colnames(file)),
  verbatimTextOutput("results")
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.table::fread(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    mytable <- read.csv(input$file$datapath) %>% as_tibble()
    req(mytable)
    updateSelectInput(session, "sel", label = "select", choices = colnames(mytable))
  })
  
  output$results <- renderPrint({
    length(unique(data()[,input$sel]))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

################### solution ######################

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  appdata <- reactive({
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    mydf <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)
    updateSelectInput(session, "sel", label = "select", choices = colnames(mydf))
  })
  
  output$results <- renderPrint({
    cat(input$sel, '\n')
    length(unique(appdata()[[input$sel]]))
  })
  
}
```

It does work for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data object returned by `fread` is a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
data <- function(){ as.data.table(mtcars)}
length(unique(data()[,1]))
#> [1] 1

nrow(unique(data()[,1]))
#> [1] 25
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The reason for this is that with a data.frame / data.table, data[,1] returns another data.frame / data.table (a list of list with 1 column).
`length` gives the number of columns, `nrow` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ```nrow``` definitely worked in already existed data like ```mtcars```  but not for input ```.csv``` data.

Comment: does nrow also return 1? Could you provide a sample of the data getting using [dput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput)?

Comment: Sure. structure(list(q1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), q3 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), q5 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2), hospital = c("yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")). It keeps showing me ```Error: incorrect number of dimensions```.

Comment: the first column of the data you provided contains 2 unique values : 1, 2, so nrow returns 2.  From the error you mention, I think there's a mismatch with the data() function from R base dataset. What happens if you type data() in the console? Could you try renaming data()  in appdata()?

Comment: Oh it worked when renaming from ```data()``` to ```appdata()```! I appreicate it. But only works ```nrow(unique(appdata()[,1]))```, not ```nrow(unique(appdata()[, input$sel]))```. My purpose is to check the number of ```input$sel```, not just designated columns. ```nrow(unique(appdata()[, "input$sel"]))``` also doesn't work for me. Is there any way I can do to check the reactive ```nrow(unique())```?

Comment: you could try to debug by inserting `cat(input$sel,'\n')` one line before the unique to see in console what is the value the UI is setting in input.