# How can I transpose a time series to a matrix without losing Time Series type?

Tags: r, time, time-series

I have a Time Series object, but I would like to transpose it in such a way that I will obtain a matrix with one column without losing the TS type.

Something like:

```
Time-Series[1:492 , 1] from 1976 to 2017
```

Every time I try to manipulate the time series, it will lose the TS "type", becoming `num`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: could you [use `dput`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput) to provide a sample of the time serie?

Answer (score 0):

**1) dim** Assuming that you have a `ts` series such as the one shown below try setting its dimensions using `dim<-` :

```
tt <- ts(1:10, start = 2000, freq = 4)
dim(tt) <- c(length(tt), 1)

dim(tt)
## [1] 10  1

class(tt)
## [1] "ts"
```

**1a)** This can alternately be written as:

```
tt <- ts(1:10, start = 2000, freq = 4)
tt2 <- `dim<-`(tt, c(length(tt), 1))

dim(tt2)
## [1] 10  1

class(tt2)
## [1] "ts"

frequency(tt2)
## [1] 4

start(tt2)
## [1] 2000    1
```

**2) cbind** An alternative is to use `cbind`.  Note that it may not display as 10x1 but it is internally which can be checked using `dim(...)`.

```
cbind(tt, tt)[, 1, drop = FALSE]
```

**3) zoo** Unfortunately `cbind(tt)` does not give a 10x1 result as one might expect but we can convert to zoo, use `cbind` and convert back.  Again it does not display as 10x1 but internally it is 10x1 and can be checked using `dim(...)`.

```
library(zoo)
as.ts(cbind(as.zoo(tt)))
```

Most manipulations using zoo are more straight forward than with `ts` so you could alternately just use zoo objects.