# Group by function query

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

Hi guys i am new to R,

While i have attached screenshot of the df i am working with                     (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUz4l.png), here is a short description

I have a data frame with a total of 7 columns, one of which is a month column, rest of the 6 columns are (integer) values and these also have empty rows

Need to summarise by count of all the 6 columns and group them by month

tried the following code: `group_by(Month) %>% summarise(count=n(),na.omit())`

get the following error:
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
x argument "object" is missing, with no default
i Input `..2` is `na.omit()`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Month = "1".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Can someone please assist?

[head of data][1]  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/stfoG.png)

```
> dput(head(Dropoff))
structure(list(Start.Date = c("01-11-2019 06:07", "01-11-2019 06:07", 
"01-11-2019 06:08", "01-11-2019 06:08", "02-11-2019 06:08", "02-11-2019 06:07"
), End.Date = c("01-11-2019 06:12", "01-11-2019 09:28", "01-11-2019 10:02", 
"01-11-2019 13:05", "02-11-2019 06:13", "02-11-2019 06:16"), 
    Month = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "11"), class = "factor"), nps = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 
    9L), effort = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L), knowledge = c(NA, 
    NA, 5L, NA, NA, 5L), confidence = c(5L, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, NA
    ), listening = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA), fcr = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), fixing.issues = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

id like the output to look something like this

| Month | count of nps | count of effort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | xxx |
| 2 | xxx | xxx |
| 11 | 6 | 6 |

....so on (count)for all the variables

the following

```
df%>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

provides this output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3nxv.png
this is not what i am hoping for

Comment: Can you post an example of your data, e.g. with `dput(head(DF))`?

Comment: head of data added

Comment: Please use `dput` and paste it as text, so people can use the data as example.

Comment: i am not sure how exactly that is done mate, apologies

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: Yes it helps. Also please provide the desired outcome, given the input. What is your intention of using the `na.omit()` ?

Comment: Please check the format of the desired output

Comment: there are NA in all other columns except the nps column, however i cannot exclude the data from the corresponding nps column for all other variables and i am assuming na.omit will exclude the na,  if the run the command without excluding the NAs i do not get the count of any other column except the first (nps) column

Answer (score 0):

looks like the `na.omit()` causes problems in this case. Given that you want to count `NA` but not have them in any following sum, you might use

```
df[is.na(df)] = 0
```

and then

```
df %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

Comment: thanks marvin, however that didnt help it  what that did was group by month and provided a count of the first variable

Comment: What exactly is your expected output on the example data you provided above?

Comment: ok i will need to figure how to use the comments section to illustrate my point, any suggestions?

Comment: added desired outcome to op

Comment: thank you. One more question: How do you define "count"? Do you want to count how many entries are non-NA? Or a sum?

Comment: Not the sum but the total number of entries or total of the rows for that header, does that make sense? excluding NAs or non NAs as you said

Comment: i meant counting total non NAs, sorry for ther confusion mate

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the clarifications. The semi-manual solution

```
df %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(
  c_nps= sum(!is.na(nps)),
  c_effort= sum(!is.na(effort)),
  c_knowledge= sum(!is.na(knowledge)),
  c_confidence= sum(!is.na(confidence)),
  c_listening= sum(!is.na(listening)),
  c_fcr= sum(!is.na(fcr))
)
```

should do the trick. Since it's only 6 columns to be summarized, I would use the manual specification over an automated implementation (i.e. count non-NA in all other columns).

It results in

```
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  Month c_nps c_effort c_knowledge c_confidence c_listening c_fcr
  <fct> <int>    <int>       <int>        <int>       <int> <int>
1 11        6        6           2            3           1     6
```

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thanks marvin,  i will use this one too

Answer (score 0):

From you example I understand, that you want to count the non-NA values in every column.

```
Dropoff %>% group_by(Month) %>%
summarise_at(vars(nps:fixing.issues), list(count=~sum(!is.na(.x))))
```

- `summarize_at`: The term performs a summarize at every column given in the `vars()` expression. Here I chose all columns from `nps` to `fixing.issues`.
- As summarizing function (which describes how the data is summarized), I defined to count all non-NA values. The syntax is to give all functions as named list. Here the `~` does the same as `function(x)`. A more lengthy way to write it would be: `function(x) sum(!is.na(x))`
- The "count" expression works as follows: check the vector of the column (x) if those are NA values `is.na`. The `!` negates this expression. As this is a vector with only true/false values, you can just count the true values with `sum`.
- The expression works for all kind of column types (text, numbers, ...)

Giving the result:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  Month nps_count effort_count knowledge_count confidence_count listening_count fcr_count fixing.issues_count
  <fct>     <int>        <int>           <int>            <int>           <int>     <int>               <int>
1 11            6            6               2                3               1         6                   0
```

If that is not what you are aiming at, please precise your question.

Comment: Thats perfect mate!, Thank you so much

Comment: if i am not asking for much, could you please break down how this code works, just so i am clear?

Comment: will we need to modify the code in anyway if we have a character variable column and need a count for it just the same? (text feedback from clients)

Comment: @IqbalS I have added a bit more of explanation.

Comment: that really helps! thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: @IqbalS Please mark this answer as accepted, if it gave you your solution to the problem. Thx