# creating a nice table in R and using the format() function to create digits

Tags: r, datatable, rounding

I have written the following code to create a table in R.
However, I cannot seem to get the `format()` digits command to work.
I have a specific column `"Population Mean"` that I would like to separate the numbers in with digits ",".

'''

```
knitr::kable(mean_pop_1, "pipe", 
col.name=c("Country", "Population Mean"), 
align = c("l", "c"), 
caption = "Top 10 Countries Mean Population", format(","))
```

I receive this error:

**Error in round(x[, j], digits[j]) :
non-numeric argument to mathematical function**
'''

Data frame:

```
country       Population_mean
   <fct>                   <dbl>
 1 China              958160052.
 2 India              701130740.
 3 United States      228211232.
 4 Indonesia          148322833.
 5 Brazil             122312127.
 6 Japan              111758808 
 7 Pakistan            93683386.
 8 Bangladesh          90755395.
 9 Germany             77547043.
10 Nigeria             73708018.
```

Here the code for the example above:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("China", "India", "United States", 
                      "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Japan", "Pakistan", 
                       "Bangladesh", "Germany", "Nigeria"), 
                      Population_mean = c(958160052, 701130740, 
                       228211232, 148322833, 122312127, 111758808, 
                       93683386, 90755395, 77547043, 73708018)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a little reproducible dataset, this will help SO community to find the best solution for you.

Comment: Hi :-), I've added some data. "Country" and "Population_mean" are the headers

Comment: Hi Maria thank you. This could help for next questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. When I asked a little reproducible example I refer to using "dput" command as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput, I will edit your question as soon as possible.

Comment: learning everyday - thank you for reviewing my question :-D

Comment: @LucaCoding - its the "format" function in the code above that is giving me some trouble. I need a thousand separator in the "population mean" column

Comment: Great that you have found a solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232855/discussion-between-lucacoding-and-maria-hoffmann-jensen).

Answer (score -1):

```
knitr::kable(mean_pop_1, "pipe", format.args = list(big.mark = ","),
   col.name=c("Country", "Population Mean"), 
   align = c("l", "r"), caption = "Top 10 Countries Mean Population")
```

Comment: Please don't just post "code-only" answers. Give some insight and explanation.