# How to add additional statistics on top of a combined ggplot2 graph that uses a multi-variable object or two separate objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I have a ggplot2 graph which plots two separate violin plots onto one graph, given by this example (thanks to @jared_mamrot for providing it):

```
library(tidyverse)

data("Puromycin")
head(Puromycin)


dat1 <- Puromycin %>% 
  filter(state == "treated")
dat2 <- Puromycin %>% 
  filter(state == "untreated")

mycp <- ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data = dat1, aes(x= state, y = conc, colour = "Puromycin (Treatment1)")) + 
  geom_violin(data = dat2, aes(x= state, y = conc, colour = "Puromycin (Treatment2)")) 
mycp
```

[image: mycp output]

I would like to add a boxplot or other summary statistics such as those in http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization and https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/STAT3022/r/current/Misc/data-visualization-2.1.pdf, but trying the code suggested in those places does not change the original plot.

```
mycp + geom_boxplot()
```

Thanks for reading and hopefully this makes sense!

**UPDATE** ==========================================================================

So the above example does not reflect exactly my situation I realize now. Essentially, I want to apply statistics onto a combined ggplot2 graph that uses two separate objects as its variables (here `TNBC_List1` and `ER_List1`) Here is an example that does (sorry for the longer example, I will admit I am having trouble creating a simpler reproducible example and I am very new to coding in general):

```
# Libraries -------------------------------------------------------------

library(BiocManager)
library(GEOquery) 
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(Matrix) 
library(devtools)
library(Seurat) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(cowplot) 
library(SAVER) 
library(metap)
library(multtest)



# Loading Raw Data into RStudio ---------------------------------- 

filePaths = getGEOSuppFiles("GSE75688") 
tarF <- list.files(path = "./GSE75688/", pattern = "*.tar", full.names = TRUE) 
tarF
untar(tarF, exdir = "./GSE75688/") 
gzipF <- list.files(path = "./GSE75688/", pattern = "*.gz", full.names = TRUE) 
ldply(.data = gzipF, .fun = gunzip) 

list.files(path = "./GSE75688/", full.names = TRUE)
list.files(path = "./GSE75688/", pattern = "\\.txt$",full.names = TRUE)


# full matrix ----------------------------------------------------------

fullmat <- read.table(file = './GSE75688//GSE75688_GEO_processed_Breast_Cancer_raw_TPM_matrix.txt', 
                      sep = '\t', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fullmat <- data.frame(fullmat[,-1], row.names=fullmat[,1])
colnames(fullmat) <- as.character(fullmat[1, ])
fullmat <- fullmat[-1,]
fullmat <- as.matrix(fullmat)


# BC01 ER+ matrix -----------------------------------------------------------
BC01mat <- grep(pattern =c("^BC01") , x = colnames(fullmat), value = TRUE)
BC01mat = fullmat[,grepl(c("^BC01"),colnames(fullmat))]
BC01mat = BC01mat[,!grepl("^BC01_Pooled",colnames(BC01mat))]
BC01mat = BC01mat[,!grepl("^BC01_Tumor",colnames(BC01mat))]

BC01pdat <- data.frame("samples" = colnames(BC01mat), "treatment" = "ER+")


# BC07 TNBC matrix -----------------------------------------------------------
BC07mat <- grep(pattern =c("^BC07") , x = colnames(fullmat), value = TRUE)
BC07mat <- fullmat[,grepl(c("^BC07"),colnames(fullmat))]
BC07mat <- BC07mat[,!grepl("^BC07_Pooled",colnames(BC07mat))]
BC07mat <- BC07mat[,!grepl("^BC07_Tumor",colnames(BC07mat))]
BC07mat <- BC07mat[,!grepl("^BC07LN_Pooled",colnames(BC07mat))]
BC07mat <- BC07mat[,!grepl("^BC07LN",colnames(BC07mat))]

BC07pdat <- data.frame("samples" = colnames(BC07mat), "treatment" = "TNBC")



#merge samples together =========================================================================

joined <- cbind(BC01mat, BC07mat)

pdat_joined <- rbind(BC01pdat, BC07pdat)


#fdat ___________________________________________________________________________________

fdat <- grep(pattern =c("gene_name|gene_type") , x = colnames(fullmat), value = TRUE)
fdat <- fullmat[,grepl(c("gene_name|gene_type"),colnames(fullmat))]

fdat <- as.data.frame(fdat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fdat <- setNames(cbind(rownames(fdat), fdat, row.names = NULL), 
                 c("ensembl_id", "gene_short_name", "gene_type"))

rownames(pdat_joined) <- pdat_joined$samples 
rownames(fdat) = make.names(fdat$gene_short_name, unique=TRUE)
rownames(joined) <- rownames(fdat)

# Create Seurat Object __________________________________________________________________
joined <- as.data.frame(joined)
sobj_pre <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = joined)
sobj_pre <-AddMetaData(sobj_pre,metadata=pdat_joined)
head(sobj_pre@meta.data)
#gene name input
sobj_pre[["RNA"]]@meta.features<-fdat
head(sobj_pre[["RNA"]]@meta.features)

#Downstream analysis -------------------------------------------------------

sobj <- sobj_pre

sobj <- FindVariableFeatures(object = sobj, mean.function = ExpMean, dispersion.function = LogVMR, nfeatures = 2000)
sobj <- ScaleData(object = sobj, features = rownames(sobj), block.size = 2000)
sobj <- RunPCA(sobj, npcs = 100, ndims.print = 1:10, nfeatures.print = 5)


sobj <- FindNeighbors(sobj, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:4, nn.eps = 0.5) 
sobj <- FindClusters(sobj, resolution = 1, n.start = 10)
umap.method = 'umap-learn'
metric = 'correlation'
sobj <- RunUMAP(object = sobj, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:4,min.dist = 0.5, seed.use = 123)

p0 <- DimPlot(sobj, reduction = "umap", pt.size = 0.1,label=TRUE) + ggtitle(label = "Title")
p0


# ER+ score computation -------------------

ERlist <- list(c("CPB1", "RP11-53O19.1", "TFF1", "MB", "ANKRD30B",
                 "LINC00173", "DSCAM-AS1", "IGHG1", "SERPINA5", "ESR1",
                 "ILRP2", "IGLC3", "CA12", "RP11-64B16.2", "SLC7A2",
                 "AFF3", "IGFBP4", "GSTM3", "ANKRD30A", "GSTT1", "GSTM1",
                 "AC026806.2", "C19ORF33", "STC2", "HSPB8", "RPL29P11",
                 "FBP1", "AGR3", "TCEAL1", "CYP4B1", "SYT1", "COX6C",
                 "MT1E", "SYTL2", "THSD4", "IFI6", "K1AA1467", "SLC39A6",
                 "ABCD3", "SERPINA3", "DEGS2", "ERLIN2", "HEBP1", "BCL2",
                 "TCEAL3", "PPT1", "SLC7A8", "RP11-96D1.10", "H4C8",
                 "PI15", "PLPP5", "PLAAT4", "GALNT6", "IL6ST", "MYC",
                 "BST2", "RP11-658F2.8", "MRPS30", "MAPT", "AMFR", "TCEAL4",
                 "MED13L", "ISG15", "NDUFC2", "TIMP3", "RP13-39P12.3", "PARD68"))

sobj <- AddModuleScore(object = sobj, features = ERlist, name = "ER_List") 



#TNBC computation -------------------


tnbclist <- list(c("FABP7", "TSPAN8", "CYP4Z1", "HOXA10", "CLDN1",
                   "TMSB15A", "C10ORF10", "TRPV6", "HOXA9", "ATP13A4",
                   "GLYATL2", "RP11-48O20.4", "DYRK3", "MUCL1", "ID4", "FGFR2",
                   "SHOX2", "Z83851.1", "CD82", "COL6A1", "KRT23", "GCHFR",
                   "PRICKLE1", "GCNT2", "KHDRBS3", "SIPA1L2", "LMO4", "TFAP2B",
                   "SLC43A3", "FURIN", "ELF5", "C1ORF116", "ADD3", "EFNA3",
                   "EFCAB4A", "LTF", "LRRC31", "ARL4C", "GPNMB", "VIM", 
                   "SDR16C5", "RHOV", "PXDC1", "MALL", "YAP1", "A2ML1",
                   "RP1-257A7.5", "RP11-353N4.6", "ZBTB18", "CTD-2314B22.3", "GALNT3",
                   "BCL11A", "CXADR", "SSFA2", "ADM", "GUCY1A3", "GSTP1",
                   "ADCK3", "SLC25A37", "SFRP1", "PRNP", "DEGS1", "RP11-110G21.2",
                   "AL589743.1", "ATF3", "SIVA1", "TACSTD2", "HEBP2"))
sobj <- AddModuleScore(object = sobj, features = tnbclist, name = "TNBC_List") 


#ggplot2 issue ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sobj[["ClusterName"]] <- Idents(object = sobj)

sobjlists <- FetchData(object = sobj, vars = c("ER_List1", "TNBC_List1", "ClusterName"))
library(reshape2)
melt(sobjlists, id.vars = c("ER_List1", "TNBC_List1", "ClusterName"))
p <- ggplot() + geom_violin(data = sobjlists, aes(x= ClusterName, y = ER_List1, fill = ER_List1, colour = "ER+ Signature"))+ geom_violin(data = sobjlists, aes(x= ClusterName, y = TNBC_List1, fill = TNBC_List1, colour="TNBC Signature"))
```

**Extension** ======================================================================

If you want to do this but with two objects (`sobjlists1` and `sobjlists2`, for example) instead of what my example showed (two variables but one object), `rbind` the two and then do what @StupidWolf says

```
library(reshape2)
sobjlists1= melt(sobjlists1, id.vars = "treatment")
sobjlists2= melt(sobjlists2, id.vars = "treatment")

combosobjlists <- rbind(sobjlists1, sobjlists2)
```

and then continue on with their code using `combosobjlists`:

```
ggplot(combosobjlists,aes(x= ClusterName, y = value)) + 
geom_violin(aes(fill=variable)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(col=variable),
width = 0.2,position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Hope this thread helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include just the minimum code to show your problem. Like in your example, there's no need to start with the whole `seurat` processing. You can just provide the data.frame with dput() and we can see the issue with ggplot2 , see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput).

Create some example data:

```
library(Seurat)
library(ggplot2)

genes = c(unlist(c(ERlist,tnbclist)))
mat = matrix(rnbinom(500*length(genes),mu=500,size=1),ncol=500)
rownames(mat) = genes
colnames(mat) = paste0("cell",1:500)
sobj = CreateSeuratObject(mat)
sobj = NormalizeData(sobj)
```

Add some made-up cluster:

```
sobj$ClusterName = factor(sample(0:1,ncol(sobj),replace=TRUE))
```

Add your module score:

```
sobj = AddModuleScore(object = sobj, features = tnbclist, 
name = "TNBC_List",ctrl=5)
sobj = AddModuleScore(object = sobj, features = ERlist, 
name = "ER_List",ctrl=5)
```

We get the data, what you need to do is to pivot it long correctly. Plotting it twice with ggplot2 is going to cause all kinds of problem:

```
sobjlists = FetchData(object = sobj, vars = c("ER_List1", "TNBC_List1", "ClusterName"))

 head(sobjlists)
         ER_List1   TNBC_List1 ClusterName
cell1 -0.05391108 -0.008736057           1
cell2  0.07074816 -0.039064126           1
cell3  0.08688374 -0.066967324           1
cell4 -0.12503649  0.120665057           0
cell5  0.05356685 -0.072293651           0
cell6 -0.20053804  0.178977042           1
```

Should look like this:

```
library(reshape2)
sobjlists = melt(sobjlists, id.vars = "ClusterName")

  ClusterName variable       value
1           1 ER_List1 -0.05391108
2           1 ER_List1  0.07074816
3           1 ER_List1  0.08688374
4           0 ER_List1 -0.12503649
5           0 ER_List1  0.05356685
6           1 ER_List1 -0.20053804
```

Now we plot:

```
ggplot(sobjlists,aes(x= ClusterName, y = value)) + 
geom_violin(aes(fill=variable)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(col=variable),
width = 0.2,position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for your help and your explanation for the example as well!

Answer (score 0):

for you to be able to use the data within a plot without specifying it (like `geom_boxplot()` ), you need to put the data in the `ggplot()` function call. Then the following functions are able to inherit them.

You also do not need an extra violin plot per color

```
library(tidyverse)

data("Puromycin")
head(Puromycin)



mycp <- ggplot(Puromycin,aes(x= state, y = conc, colour=state))+geom_violin()
mycp + geom_boxplot(width=0.1, color= "black") + 
  scale_color_discrete(
                       labels= c("Puromycin (Treatment1)","Puromycin (Treatment2)")
                       )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Sandwichnick! I should've been clearer in my example and question. My particular data takes two differently named columns (two different "condition groups") from the same dataset and plots them side by side on the same graph. Because they are two different objects though, it can't be placed in ggplot(), or it just separates them out into separate plots. I'll change the question to reflect this, but thank you very much again for your answer!