# How to get object of class summary.averaging into a tidy format for use in jtools::plot_summs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

R newbie here, looking  to create a forestplot using the results of several model-averaged candidate model sets. I apologize in advance as this is quite an involved question, but I greatly appreciate any advice or code you can share to help me get this visualized!

I've saved model-averaged results from several models(different species) into one CSV that is structured like this:

| Species | coefficient | Estimate | Std.Error | AdjustedSE | zvalue | Pr(>z) | CI.min | CI.max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mongoose | DT_River | -0.685705266 | 0.523246095 | 0.52963788 | 1.294668095 | 0.1954348 | -1.734615159 | -0.015033231 |
| Mongoose | DT_CM | 0.166817983 | 0.335013282 | 0.338030022 | 0.493500493 | 0.621659 | -0.185497503 | 1.359723055 |
| Mongoose | DT_Human | 0.179868595 | 0.391709753 | 0.39388355 | 0.456654244 | 0.6479196 | 0.012027307 | 1.6520409 |
| Mongoose | cbFI | -0.050836906 | 0.210660252 | 0.213638062 | 0.237958093 | 0.8119136 | -1.328749428 | 0.512378572 |
| Mongoose | lnMB | -0.041905179 | 0.19077529 | 0.193659704 | 0.21638564 | 0.8286872 | -1.255336049 | 0.532397428 |
| Large Duiker | DT_River | -1.580215953 | 0.673519724 | 0.684880124 | 2.307288382 | 0.0210387 | -2.922556329 | -0.237875577 |
| Large Duiker | DT_CM | -0.324249972 | 0.41698415 | 0.420610517 | 0.770903149 | 0.4407643 | -1.388148857 | 0.055833773 |
| Large Duiker | lnMB | -0.256614391 | 0.50827175 | 0.51098689 | 0.502193688 | 0.6155313 | -1.998775227 | -0.107175859 |

So, as you can see I have multiple species and multiple covariates per species. What I want to do is **create a forestplot of only the estimates and the CI.min and CI.max for each estimate, for each species, with each species in a different color**. Ideally I'd like to make something like the below using plot_summs or plot_coeffs, but I can't seem to make those functions plot data when it is in the format I have it above.

[image: Forest plot showing beta estimates and std. error for four species and six covariates]

ANY help is appreciated!

Comment: if you dput the output which would be used as input for the plot that would be really easy ti build the dataframe

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! I don't think I understand what you're saying. I do have a dataframe, which is in the table in my question. What I want to know is how to create a forestplot from my dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput this might of use what im trying to say " What I want to know is how to create a forestplot from my dataframe " yes since if you use dput it would be easy to create the data frame

Comment: i tried using your data given but the column are messed up ..so if you can give dput it would be easy to replicate

Comment: oh, I just realized my table was messed up due to | symbols in one of the headers. I have fixed it.