# Univariate Cox analysis for a gene list

Tags: r, cox-regression, survival

I'm trying to plot this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQkD.jpg)

using this code form GitHub:

```
PP<- data.frame()
for (i in names(tt)) {
   dd <- tt[[i]]
   for(j in colnames(dd)[4:ncol(dd)]){
      scox <- summary( coxph(Surv(OS.time,OS) ~ get(j),dd))
      p <- compareC(dd$OS.time, dd$OS, dd$IRLS,dd[,j])$pval
      uni <- rbind(uni, data.frame(ID=i,A=j,
                            HR=scox$conf.int[,1],
                            HR.95L=scox$conf.int[,3],
                            HR.95R=scox$conf.int[,4],
                            pvalue=scox$coefficients[,5],
                            cindex=scox$concordance[1]%>%as.numeric(),
                            cse=scox$concordance[2]%>%as.numeric(),
                            CP=p))}}
```

how this loop works? my input is a gene expression vector (TCGA) and i wanted to get a list of significant prognostic features (genes).

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your data for reproducibility with `dput(dd)`.

Comment: Thanks dear Jang, I'm not getting what you exactly mean. may you state more clear.

Comment: I mean I want you to share your data using `dput(your data)` in `R` to help your problem :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49995752/11926169

Comment: With no loop indices on the LHS of assignments you will overwrite the values of all calulations except the last ones.

Comment: oh okay, my data.frame is like this:600 samples in columns and 500 genes in rows