# problems with changing color in R

Tags: r

I have  a dataset that is very small. It is this

```
activity <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female","male", "female", "male", "female"),
  Season  = c("Spring","Spring","Summer","Summer","Fall","Fall","Winter","Winter"),
  n = c(450,280,890,720,300,250,300,250),
  check.names = FALSE
)
dput(activity)
```

| Gender | Season | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Spring | 450 |
| Female | Spring | 280 |
| Male | Summer | 890 |
| Female | Summer | 720 |
| Male | Fall | 300 |
| Female | Fall | 250 |
| Male | Winter | 300 |
| Female | Winter | 250 |

I want to create a histogram to distinguish between male and female activity during season

```
ggplot(data = activity, mapping = aes(  x = Season,
        y = n)) + geom_bar(  mapping = aes(fill = Gender), 
        position = "dodge",
        stat = "identity") + ggtitle (Activity by Season and Gender)
```

This code above works well, but the colors are really ugly. I want blue for men and red for woman.

I gave that code below to change it

```
ggplot(data = activity, mapping = aes(  x = Season,
        y = n)) + geom_bar(  mapping = aes(fill = Gender), palette= c("blue","red"),
        position = "dodge",
        stat = "identity")
```

The code doesn't work. What I am doing wrong???

I had this from a programming book and there it works like this, but this code doesn't change the colors

Comment: Could you please include the output of [`dput(activity)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput) in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? I am very new to Stackoverflow. How can I do that dput(activity)?

Comment: Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput).

Comment: You can use `dput()` function on your dataframe and output it in your question

Comment: Is it now okay? I try it but seems not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
ggplot(data = activity, mapping = aes(  x = Season,
        y = n)) + geom_bar(  mapping = aes(fill = Gender), 
        position = "dodge",
        stat = "identity") + ggtitle (Activity by Season and Gender)
```

> The code above works well.

No, it doesn't. You forgot to wrap `Activity by Season and Gender` in quotes.

And this is what you were looking for.

```r
ggplot(data = activity, mapping = aes(  x = Season,y = n)) + geom_bar(  mapping = aes(fill = Gender), position = "dodge",stat = "identity") + ggtitle ("Activity by Season and Gender") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

I just added `+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))` to the end of the command.