# Match the 'keys' with dataframe data to display 'values'

Tags: python

How the `d.keys()` in `d` can match with the `df['month']` to display the `d.values`?

If let say the dataframe 's data 01/01/2022, 01/02/2022, 01/03/2022, ...etc
How the `1` in the `df['month']` match with the `d.keys()` to display `Jan`?

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Settlement_Date']).dt.month


d = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun',...}
```

Comment: Could you please include the output of [`dput(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput) in your question?

Comment: you can do `df["month"].replace(d)` it will replace month numbers with corresponding month value in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply function on the data frame. Lets go by your example:

```
month_labels = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August',9: 'Spet', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}

df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['month'].apply(lambda x: month_labels[x])
```

Also, if you have specific use case of converting number to dates, you can use `.dt.month_name()` function in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the dictionary to the months -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1-Jan-2022', '1-Jun-2022', freq='M'), columns=['dates'])
d = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun'}
df['dates'].dt.month.map(d)
```

**Output**

```
0    Jan
1    Feb
2    Mar
3    Apr
4    May
Name: dates, dtype: object
```