# How index columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to reshape my data, I have tried multiple times with transpose and gather but did not worked.
I have a df like this

```
        [,1]                                                                                                            
loc         "Envigado, Antioquia"                                                                                           
name        "almacenes exito s a "                                                                                          
x           "https://in.linkedin.com/company/almacenes-exito-s-a-"                                                          
Descripcion "Somos un negocio que se adapta a las nuevas formas de consumo de los clientes. A través de la inno" [truncated]
loc.1       "Malambo, Atlántico"                                                                                            
name.1      "acerias de colombia   acesco"  
x.1
Description.1
loc.2                                                                                
>
```

Then I want to create a df with columns called name, location, x, Descripcion and index all this data separated by .x to their determinated column based on the word (loc, name, x, Descripcion )

expected output:

```
loc                   name                   x                         Descripcion
"Envigado, Antioquia" "almacenes exito s a " "https://in.linkedin.com "Somos un negocio que se adapta a las nuevas formas de consumo de los clientes. A través de la inno"
```

rest of loc.1, loc.x, name.1 ... loc.x x.1 ... x.x descripcion.1 ... descripcion.x will appear down of each column

the dput is

```
dput(head(xd))
structure(list("Envigado, Antioquia", "almacenes exito s a ", 
    "https://in.linkedin.com/company/almacenes-exito-s-a-", "Somos un negocio que se adapta a las nuevas formas de consumo de los clientes. A través de la innovación, la transformación digital, las experiencias y la sostenibilidad, respondemos a un entorno competitivo y aportamos al desarrollo de los lugares donde tenemos presencia.\n\nSomos parte de la plataforma líder del retail más grande de Suramérica, con presencia en Colombia con las marcas Éxito, Carulla, Super Inter, Surtimax, Surtimayorista y Viva, y en Uruguay con Grupo Disco y Grupo Devoto. Además, en Argentina, con Libertad y Paseo.\n\nContamos con estrategias diferenciales con la que nos adaptamos a las nuevas formas de consumo:\n\n- Innovación en formatos de valor y en nuevas formas de pago sin fricciones para el cuidado del cliente.\n\n- Estrategia omnicliente, para ofrecer al cliente lo que quiere, cuando quiere, donde quiere.\n\n- Monetización del tráfico, a través de los centros comerciales y programas de fidelidad. Además de los negocios complementarios.\n\n- Sostenibilidad: transformación a partir de un negocio que genera valor compartido.", 
    "Malambo, Atlántico", "acerias de colombia   acesco"), dim = c(6L, 
1L), dimnames = list(c("loc", "name", "x", "Descripcion", "loc.1", 
"name.1"), NULL))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a `dput(head(df))` as well as expected output?

Comment: the dput is ```<structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), dim = c(6L, 
1L), dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")```
 and the expected output is updated on question

Comment: He didn't mean literally `dput(head(df))` he meant, take your list and put it in `dput` function and then give us the result of the dput

Comment: @lasagna Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput.

Comment: Your expected output isn't clear enough, I kinda think I know what you're saying but it's a bit incomplete