# Issues with layout in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-markdown, ggplotly

I'm taking over a project from another more experienced user of Rmd, the code ran for her but now that I'm trying, the following code is throwing this error:

```
#Output the plot using plotly
a<- plotly::ggplotly(cstr_volume_graph) %>% 
  layout(legend = list( #this layout bit is to change position of legend, although it's not working properly - *DEV_NOTE
  orientation = "h" 
)) %>% 
  layout(annotations = list(x = 0 , y = 1.05, text = paste0("CSTR Volumes for Site: ",params$site_name), showarrow = F, 
xref='paper', yref='paper')) #Title of the chart
```

```
Error in order(data[["x"]]) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

This is the code that follows for context:

```
b<-plotly::ggplotly(context_volume_graph) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(
  orientation = "h"
)) %>% 
  layout(annotations = list(x = 0.7 , y = 1.05, text = paste0("Short Custodial Sentences for Site:",params$site_name), showarrow = F, 
xref='paper', yref='paper'))

subplot(a,b)
```

I've installed all of the relevant packages and tried using *theme(legend.position= x)* but nothing is seeming to work, it still throws the same error. More to the issue I'm not actually sure what the code she has written is intended to do!

This is the output for dput(cstr_volume_graph):

```
structure(list(data = structure(list(month_yr = structure(numeric(0), class = "yearmon"), 
    cstr_type = character(0), volumes = integer(0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), layers = list(
    <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
    x = ~month_yr, y = ~volumes, colour = ~cstr_type), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = structure(list(line = structure(list(colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, lineend = "butt", arrow = FALSE, 
        inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", "element"
    )), rect = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = "black", 
        size = 0.5, linetype = 1, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
    "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
        colour = "black", size = 11, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
        angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
    "element")), title = NULL, aspect.ratio = NULL, axis.title = NULL, 
        axis.title.x = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, vjust = 1, 
            angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.75, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 2.75, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.bottom = NULL, axis.title.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 1, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 2.75, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.y.left = NULL, axis.title.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 0, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 2.75), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = "grey30", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.2, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 2.2, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.bottom = NULL, axis.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 2.2, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.y.left = NULL, axis.text.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 2.2), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(colour = "grey20", 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.ticks.x = NULL, axis.ticks.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.y = NULL, axis.ticks.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.y.right = NULL, axis.ticks.length = structure(2.75, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL, axis.ticks.length.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y.right = NULL, 
        axis.line = structure(list(colour = "black", size = structure(1, class = "rel"), 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.line.x.bottom = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, axis.line.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.line.y.right = NULL, legend.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.margin = structure(c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
        5.5), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", "unit", 
        "unit_v2")), legend.spacing = structure(11, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, 
        legend.key = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.key.size = structure(1.2, unit = 3L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, 
        legend.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = NULL, legend.justification = "center", 
        legend.box = NULL, legend.box.just = NULL, legend.box.margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), unit = 1L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.box.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.box.spacing = structure(11, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.background = structure(list(
            fill = "white", colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.border = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(5.5, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid = structure(list(colour = "grey92", size = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.minor = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major.x = NULL, panel.grid.major.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid.minor.x = NULL, panel.grid.minor.y = NULL, 
        panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = "white", size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), plot.title = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 5.5, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.title.position = "panel", plot.subtitle = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 5.5, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(5.5, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption.position = "panel", plot.tag = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = "topleft", plot.margin = structure(c(5.5, 
        5.5, 5.5, 5.5), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.background = structure(list(
            fill = "white", colour = "black", size = structure(2, class = "rel"), 
            linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), strip.background.x = NULL, strip.background.y = NULL, 
        strip.placement = "inside", strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = "grey10", size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(2.75, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(2.75, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.text.y.left = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element"))), class = c("theme", "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), 
    coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, 
    labels = list(x = "month_yr", y = "volumes", colour = "cstr_type")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible data. You can use `dput`. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: @Shubham added above!

Comment: HI Tamzim...maybe I was not able to explain. You probably have a data that you used to create a plot (using `ggplot` and `plotly`). Could you please share that data (using `dput`) and also give the `ggplot` code.