# I want to create a function which takes Colum as a parameter to produce a bar chart of top10 values while comparing with a third column value

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sa1q.png)I have a dataset with 7 columns in which I need to create a function such that
-> it takes one column as a parameter to create a barchart of the top ten values in that column
-> with having a certain clause comparing with third column

considering sample data as the image

material as the parameter for the function and speed determines top 10 values, where material is wodden.

I just need to create the function, I know how to create the barplot and it works fine

example data
head(subset_coaster)

```
dput(subset_coaster[1:30, c("coaster_Data.name","coaster_Data.material_type","coaster_Data.speed")])
structure(list(coaster_Data.name = c("Goudurix", "Dream catcher", 
"Alucinakis", "Anaconda", "Azteka", "Bat Coaster", "Batman : Arkham Asylum", 
"Big Thunder Mountain", "EqWalizer", "Calamity Mine", "Casey Jr, le Petit Train du Cirque", 
"Cobra", "Coccinelle", "Coleoz'Arbres", "Comet", "Course de Bobsleigh", 
"Cumbres", "Le Dragon de Bei Hai", "Euro Mir", "Eurosat", "Expedition Ge Force", 
"Le Grand canyon", "Indiana Jones et le Temple du Péril", "Jaguar", 
"Cop Car Chase (1)", "Loup Garou", "Magnus Colossus", "Oki Doki", 
"SOS Numerobis", "Poseïdon"), coaster_Data.material_type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Steel", 
"Wooden", "Hybrid", "na"), class = "factor"), coaster_Data.speed = c(75, 
45, 30, 85, 55, 70, 80, 60, 76, 48, 30, 76, 36, 60, 64, 65, NA, 
NA, 80, 60, 120, 50, 58, 83, 60, 80, 92, 58, 32, 70)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please provide some data?

Comment: @NickGlättli I have added a sample dataset picture to refer

Comment: Please provide an output we can actually work with (e.g. dput(data)).

Comment: I don't understand which output??

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: I have changed the context is this right?

Comment: No, I cannot really work with that. Please run the following code and include the output in the post: `dput(subset_coaster)`

Comment: I have changed the dataset, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of your post, it is still unclear what you want from the function. Thus, here is my approach to what I think you want.

```r
df <- structure(list(coaster_Data.name = c("Goudurix", "Dream catcher", 
                                     "Alucinakis", "Anaconda", "Azteka", "Bat Coaster", "Batman : Arkham Asylum", 
                                     "Big Thunder Mountain", "EqWalizer", "Calamity Mine", "Casey Jr, le Petit Train du Cirque", 
                                     "Cobra", "Coccinelle", "Coleoz'Arbres", "Comet", "Course de Bobsleigh", 
                                     "Cumbres", "Le Dragon de Bei Hai", "Euro Mir", "Eurosat", "Expedition Ge Force", 
                                     "Le Grand canyon", "Indiana Jones et le Temple du Péril", "Jaguar", 
                                     "Cop Car Chase (1)", "Loup Garou", "Magnus Colossus", "Oki Doki", 
                                     "SOS Numerobis", "Poseïdon"), 
                     coaster_Data.material_type = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                                            levels = c("Steel", "Wooden", "Hybrid", "na"), 
                                                            class = "factor"), 
                     coaster_Data.speed = c(75, 45, 30, 85, 55, 70, 80, 60, 76, 48, 30, 76, 36, 60, 64, 65, NA, 
                                            NA, 80, 60, 120, 50, 58, 83, 60, 80, 92, 58, 32, 70)), 
                      row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

barplotting <- function(data, mat= "Steel"){
  
  require(tidyverse)
  
  data %>%
    filter(coaster_Data.material_type == mat) %>%
    arrange(desc(coaster_Data.speed)) %>%
    slice(1:10) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= coaster_Data.name, y= coaster_Data.speed))+
    geom_col()
    
}

barplotting(df, "Wooden")
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It works good enough for me! Exactly what i was looking for!!